# How to just open a .pages document from Windows or Linux and without any Apple product?

Tags: linux, iwork-pages, windows-10-v1809

Iwork pages uses a native format which can’t be opened from Openoffice nor Wordperfect nor Microsoft word…

All solutions I found involve using a macintosh or a paid Apple account whereas I was sent a document in `.pages` format and I have nothing which is Apple related.

Comment: I don’t want to modify. But just to see what’s inside.

Answer (score 3):

For just a short look, rename it to `.zip`, create a temporary folder and unzip it there. The file `preview.jpg` will contain the rendered first page of the document in 72dpi.

If you are interested in the text, you can try to filter `Index/Document.iwa` for readable text.

Comment: The problem is till for interactive graphics. Something like ᴘᴅꜰ would be better.

Comment: @user2284570 Not available - the image is just to make the embedded "quick look" functionality work. - Maybe you might want to try some of these online converters (search for "convert pages document")... unless it is confidential data, of course.

Comment: Data isn’t confidential. I got incorrect results with online converters, even those which targets the ᴘᴅꜰ format.

Comment: That's to be expected, I guess... the only software to accurately render those documents would be Pages.app. Needless to say, exactly the same goes for Word or OpenOffice documents.

Comment: yes but not at that level. I’ve the feeling of converting/opening a ᴘᴅꜰ.